# weblogic setting and javascript

Tags: java, javascript, performance, weblogic

I have a web application deployed on weblogic on a UNIX box. The app is also deployed on my local and another older UNIX box with weblogic. On my local and the older machine, the app works just fine. But on the new server, the app is very slow and Javascript functionality does not work that well. What settings could cause such an issue?

Comment: Not enought details.   Could be about your network and not WebLogic.  Can't tell from what you posted.

Comment: Javascript is client-side and won't be dependent on the server, unless you're talking about AJAX calls.

Comment: @GriffeyDog, it is the AJAX calls. It throws an Unexpected syntax error. In the old and new it's just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be due to the configuration of the new unix box. I've had similar performance problems when upgrading our sun sol box. You will have to talk to your admin to tweak your unix box configuration settings to work with your weblogic instance or vice versa. For us, it came down to the chip architecture of the new sun box which was the cause a noticeable difference in the performance. I suggest you look into the supported configurations for your Weblogic version and compare it with your new unix box and proceed from there.

Here is [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13196_01/platform/suppconfigs/configs91/91_over/overview.html) for Weblogic 9.1 and its supported configurations.